# Remove installation files at first run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I have an xml file in my winform setup project.

At first run the application uses data from this xml file, but then changes the data and don't use the xml file anymore. This is done only if the application finds the xml file in the output directory.

If I remove the xml file after the first run, on the second run I'm requested to re-install the application because some files are missing.

The xml file installation property Vital is set to False but that doesn't help.

In other words, how do I add files to the winform setup project which are needed during installation and not to run the application?

Thanks